# grails add svn revision to app.version

Tags: svn, grails, groovy, build

I'm trying to add the svn revision to my `app.version` without requiring ant or some other similar external tool. It looks like I might be able to hook into `_Events.groovy` to this, but the documentation is relatively sparse.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/automate-app-version-from-subversion-td1389908.html) link from the Grails nabble mailing list has the solution you're looking for.  Also putting the code here for completeness:

In `scripts/_Events.groovy`

```
eventWarStart = { type -> 

    println "******************* eventWarStart *****************" 
    try { 
        // initialise SVNKit 
        DAVRepositoryFactory.setup(); 
        SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl.setup(); 
        FSRepositoryFactory.setup(); 

        SVNClientManager clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(); 
        println "clientManager = " + clientManager.toString(); 
        SVNWCClient wcClient = clientManager.getWCClient(); 
        println "wcClient = " + wcClient.toString(); 

        // the svnkit equivalent of "svn info" 
        File baseFile = new File(basedir); 

        println "baseFile = " + baseFile.toString(); 
        SVNInfo svninfo = wcClient.doInfo(baseFile, SVNRevision.WORKING); 
        println "svninfo = " + svninfo.toString(); 

        def version = svninfo.getURL(); 
        println "Setting Version to: ${version}" 
        metadata.'app.version' = "${version}".toString() 
        metadata.persist() 

    } 
    catch (SVNException ex) { 
        //something went wrong 
        println "**************** SVN exception **************" 
        println ex.getMessage(); 
    } 

} // End eventWarStart()
```

Comment: This works great, except behind git svn. I have to pull off of my build server to get the app version, but this is the way to go.

Comment: This prints the SVN url, not version as suggested. I wanted the revision number so I used `def version = svninfo.revision`.

Answer (score 0):

Grails 3.x, in build.gradle, add svn revision to app version:

```
version "1.0.${getSvnRevision()}"

def getSvnRevision() {
    def proc = "svnversion".execute()
    return proc.in.text
}
```