# How can I get revision number from a remote SVN repository, using SVNKit and Java / Groovy?

Tags: java, svn, groovy, svnkit

I thought the basic answer to my question was here:
[grails add svn revision to app.version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263995/grails-add-svn-revision-to-app-version)

but it turned out that 'baseDir' has to be a physical file location and not a url -  or so it seemed.

Can anyone direct me to an example using a remote repository, that doesn't require a userid/pswd?

I have this working by issuing 'svn info *url*', but this seems a bit fragile to me. I spent maybe two hours yesterday evening searching and trying things, but without success. I can't help feeling that the solution is probably quite close to the example in the link.

Regards, John

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223554/svnkit-how-to-get-latest-revision-number-from-svn-db

Comment: @tim_yates I have now! Thanks very much. Can't imagine how I managed not to find this while searching yesterday... but I did.

Comment: I tried the second of the solutions, but that requested userid/pswd, which I have to avoid. Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: String repos = "http://svn.myco.com/svn/myco"
String url = repos+"/trunk/Subscriber"
DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();
    SVNURL svnurl = SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(url);

SVNRepositoryrepository = 
       SVNRepositoryFactory.create(svnurl);

def latestRevision = repository.getLatestRevision();

Error msg:
svn: OPTIONS of '/svn/myco/trunk/Subscriber': 401 Authorization Required (http://svn.myco.com)